# Should I polish the car myself?

Tags: maintenance, car, hyundai

I am concerned about safety (of paint) and efficiency.

My car is old (bought in 2013), and looks dull. I have never waxed or polished.

I have just learnt that these two are "things". My car has been in open parking for the most of its life.

Is polishing the right thing to do? Other suggestions are welcome.

I am thinking of using this tutorial:

https://www.thedrive.com/cleaning-detailing/36506/how-to-polish-a-car

Comment: What color is the paint?  Lighter colors are usually easier to renew than darker.  That tutorial has some decent tips but it's far from complete.

Comment: Its light see this pic for ref thanks for reply https://www.google.com/search?q=hyundai+tucson+2013+tan&safe=off&rlz=1CDGOYI_enUS793US794&hl=en-US&prmd=isvn&sxsrf=ALeKk01MuE372zh7U3fJ-gJYiuzejkYPng:1616606770821&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjps8LCucnvAhXhGVkFHQDODAMQ_AUoAXoECAwQAQ&biw=414&bih=620#imgrc=fUhEmVMvBqJtXM

Comment: @David Watson what would be some good resources to refer to?

Comment: So many variables regarding auto paint, and it's hard to find any quickly that don't sell their own products, but I came across this which again is not entirely complete but will give you an idea.      https://www.garagetooladvisor.com/auto/how-to-detail-car-exterior/

Answer (score 0):

If is is dull and you want it to shine polish it. Most cars have a clear coat with UV blocker , or the UV blocker is in the paint itself. My 2011 shines just fine if someone washes the dirt off of it ; it is garage kept . But my previous truck was parked outside and ,when clean, it also had an excellent shine ( 2004 year model). Most car finishes are now organic pigment colors rather than mineral pigments and  deteriorate if not protected from UV . If your car did not originally have UV blocker , the appearance could be improved with some polish product , but it has had some damage already. This same UV deterioration can be easily seen in acrylic headlights ( auto finishes are mostly acrylic resins ) ; my 2011 lenses are "clear as glass" , but I see newer cars with yellowish cloudy lenses - poor UV blocker. Both the acrylic resin and organic pigments in the paint are deteriorated by UV.